# Android Firebase multifetching

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get more than one object from Firebase db, but I'm getting an exception related to the `onDataChange` method.

How can I fix it and still fetch objects from db?

```
public LoadResult<List<SearchResult>> search(final String request){
    LoadResult.ResultType type = LoadResult.ResultType.UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    final List<SearchResult>searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    //// FIXME: 28.12.2016

    databaseReference.child("db").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Map<String, Pair<Lyrics, String>> map = (Map <String, Pair<Lyrics, String>>) d.getValue();
                Pair<Lyrics, String> pair = (Pair<Lyrics, String>) map.get(request);
                searchResults.add(castLyricsToSearchRes(pair.first,pair.second));
                }

            }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, databaseError.toException());
        }
    });
```

Exception that I'm getting:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  java.lang.NullPointerException
      at olegkuro.learnbyear.loaders.DBLoader$1.onDataChange(DBLoader.java:55)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5751)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1083)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:850)
      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What's the exception you're getting? Please edit your question and include the full stack trace. Be sure to also point out how the line numbers correspond to the code snippet you shared.

Comment: You didn't post the code in `search()`  that builds the returned `LoadResult` value.  If you are using `searchResults` (likely you are), it will not  yet be defined because the listener fires asynchronously.